# ASP .NET - Bind Dropdownlist using OleDbDataAdapter

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am an ASP .NET beginner, so please bear with me.

I have a database named `Product` which contains columns `ProductName` and `ProductID`.

I want to display all `ProductName` values in dropdownlist. For this, I first put all the values in a dataset and from there, I bind them to dropdownlist. But in the output, instead of `ProductName` values, I am getting the following values in dropdownlist:

> System.Data.DataRowView

(Repeated equal to the number of rows in database)

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;

public partial class Demo : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\Database2.mdb;Persist Security Info=True");
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            string query = "SELECT ProductName FROM Product";
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn);
            conn.Open();
            adapter.Fill(ds, "Table1");
            conn.Close();
            DropDownList1.DataSource = ds;
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea what I am missing here? Your help will will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to specify your [`DataValueField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datavaluefield%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [`DataTextField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datatextfield%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) properties like;

```
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "ProductName";
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "ProductName";
```